# Yii CListView widget. Trying to locate template

Tags: php, yii

I'm trying to locate a template for this CListView like below. not sure about {items}\n{pager} and where this template is located. Do you know where I can find this?

```
$this -> widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array('dataProvider' => $dataProvider, 'itemView' => '_defaultList', 'template' => "{items}\n{pager}", ));
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean "where this template is located"?
Template for this widget placed in "Your yii directory\framework\zii\widgets\"

Answer (score 0):

See the class reference for [CBaseListView](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CBaseListView#htmlOptions-detail), I was able to modify the output markup by passing some options on the properties array